# Slow draining shower

Tags: plumbing, shower

Advice please to clear shower drain. I have used bicarbonate soda and vinegar which didn’t help. Then I bought a snake auger but when I take chrome cover off shower drain, all I cannot see any sign of the hole leading to pipe work and I’ve tried feeling for it with flexible wire. If I look under the shower I can see where drain pipe goes off the trap but no entry hole when I try from shower tray.  I wondered if there was a hair trap which should lift out but plastic fitting seems to be secured into shower tray. I’ve tried turning it but no movement at all. I’d be grateful for any tips. I’d post photo but not sure how to add them. [image][image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the drain so we can see what you see?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. To post your picture, [edit] your post, then simply drag the picture into the text edit box. The site will automatically upload & host the image for you. Alternatively, you can click the "sun & mountain" icon above the text entry box and enter the picture there. If it's fighting back, upload the picture to a site like imgur.com, then paste the share link into the comments, someone will embed it for you.

Comment: Baking or better washing soda used to clean kitchen sink from fat. Shower and washroom sink acid should be used. Just vinegar a.k.a. diluted acetic acid. Stronger acid better but more dangerous.

Comment: This video shows that the drain line can have multiple bents in it making rodding difficult. https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+shower+drain+connects&&view=detail&mid=2E0D107D6B908F802F732E0D107D6B908F802F73&&FORM=VRDGAR&ru=%2Fvideos%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dhow%2Bshower%2Bdrain%2Bconnects%26%26FORM%3DVDVVXX

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with this recently with two shower/tubs.
I'm going to assume that you mean a combo and just a shower because those (at least in my experience) go straight down.

For me, it was really hard to tell which way the drain went at the bottom, but it went straight back under the tub. Please don't take this to mean that yours necessarily does.

For the first one, I put a snake down and was able to get quite a bit of hair out. The snake ended up getting stuck on the way out and I deformed it some.
With the second, I just put some lye down the drain. This isn't really ideal especially if you have a septic field, but is fast and easy.

Comment: Top photo is what I see under shower tray. Bottom photo is part that I wonder if it can be removed and if so how?